# How to set canvas ZIndex WPF button control in Click Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have three buttons lying one by one. I want to show top of all button, which i click. So that I have set canvas ZIndex in XAML Code. But I want to do this in Code Behind.

My XAML Output & Code -

[image]

```
<Button Name="Button1" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button1_Click" />
<Button Name="Button2" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="130" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button2_Click" />
<Button Name="Button3" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="260" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button3_Click" />
```

My XAML Output & Code (Check How the ZIndex was Changed)-

[image]

```
<Button Name="Button1" Canvas.ZIndex="3" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button1_Click" />
<Button Name="Button2" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="130" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button2_Click" />
<Button Name="Button3" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Content="Button1" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="260" Width="163" Height="58" FontSize="26" Click="Button3_Click" />
```

How I change the Canvas.ZIndex property in WPF button control in Click Event?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set z index in code like this:

```cs
Panel.SetZIndex(control name, int index);
```

Answer (score 7):

An attached property is set from code using by convention the SetPropertyName function.

```
Panel.SetZIndex(Button2, 0);
```

Comment: I prefer the Panel method, as that is where it is declared. And ReSharper warns of accessing a static member via a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Z-index canbe set like this..

```
 Panel.SetZIndex(Button2, 10);
```